# how 2 c++ programs call each other's class/functions on same linux box?

Tags: c++, function, sockets, pipe, fifo

I'm brand new to c++, so my vocab's probably off.

I currently make 100% ajax sites but want to work in websockets to autoupdate relevant clients.

I'm using fastcgi++ and websocket++.  I'd like to serve all data via the websocket but update the database via ajax calls.  My problem comes in when I want to have the ajax page trigger the websocket.

I've read about sockets, fifo, and pipes, but I'm not sure which one is ideal for this situation.

For two c++ programs, one ajax & one websocket, on the same linux box, how can the ajax program safely and asynchronously call a function in the websocket program?

Comment: Do you really need to have one program call a function in another? Can't you just have them both manipulate some shared state (like in a file or database)?

Comment: As I understand what you're saying, the Ajax program is going to tell the websocket++ program to do something that is part of the websocket++ program's responsibility. It has to know what it's expected to do, so worrying that this will take away from its ability to do its job makes no sense. Knowing what job you're supposed to do doesn't take away from your ability to do it, in fact, it's essential. You might want to use some kind of other structure to tell the websocket++ program when to check. You can use shared memory for that. You can use a pipe or FIFO.

Comment: That's one way to let another program know that something has changed. Writing a byte to a pipe/FIFO is another.

Comment: Having the ajax program call the websocket program (or vice versa) sounds questionable to me. I'd probably write both of those as front-ends for a single generic server. At least initially, I'd probably have them use pipes to communicate with the server.

Comment: @JoeCoderGuy: Pipes are a lot easier, and generally about the same speed. In reality, a pipe is a (small) block of shared memory, but with all the locking and such handled by the kernel. The main advantage of shared memory comes when/if you need to transfer a big block of data at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have both programs talk to the same database. If you need some way to "throw a dart" at the other to notify it to check the database, you can use shared memory or a pipe. Sending one byte through the pipe is sufficient.