# pipe "address system"

Tags: c++, ajax, pipe, websocket++, fastcgi++

Maybe I'm misunderstanding [How to make a pipe in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840109/how-to-make-a-pipe-in-c) thus http://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe, but how does the `pipe` know where to send to or receive from?

Upon a database update via an ajax page, I want that ajax program to send a message to my websocket program to update all of the other relevant users, and it's been recommended that using `pipe` would probably be best [how 2 c++ programs call each other's class/functions on same linux box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15303919/how-2-c-programs-call-each-others-class-functions-on-same-linux-box).

Is there just one pipe and all programs read it and validate the message?

---

Note: I'm using fastcgi++ and websocket++ if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want multiple independent processes to read from the pipe, you need to use a *named pipe*, also known as a [FIFO](http://linux.die.net/man/7/fifo).

Using the [`mkfifo`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mkfifo) function, one process creates a file in the file system (normally in `/tmp`). This file can then be opened for reading or writing using the normal [`open`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/open) system call by any other process that have access to that file.

Comment: Thank-you for answering!  I only want one source and one destination per pipe, but I want many pipes overall and for each program to have many pipes.  Do pipes use the file system like FIFO or use memory?

Comment: @JoeCoderGuy the file is needed for mkfifo just when creating the fifo (so the receiving process knows what to open), after that it's as per a normal pipe - data travelling through a fifo (or a pipe) **doesn't** need to go via the disk.

Comment: @JoeCoderGuy If the two processes are totally independent, i.e. two different programs, you have to use `mkfifo` to create a named pipe, as the `pipe` system call only creates an in-memory pipe. If you on the other hand `fork` the new process, so the two processes are related, doing a `pipe` call before the `fork` is okay as the file descriptors are inherited when doing the `fork`.